# Google reCAPTCHAが環境によってエラーになることがある

Tags: recaptcha

Google reCAPTCHA v2 を使って問い合わせフォームからロボット等自動プログラムからの問い合わせを排除しています。
自分のPC環境ではチェックボックスを押すことができるのですが、ユーザーのPC環境だと「サイト所有者のエラー：サイトキーのドメインが無効です」と表示されチェックボックスが表示されません。

自分もユーザーも同じくWindows10でGoogle Chromeを使っているのですが、ユーザーの方でだけ上記のエラーメッセージが表示されます。
こういった場合、どのような原因が考えられるのでしょうか？
また解決方法を教えて頂きたいです。

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js の読み込み、およびサイトキーの記述はできています。
また、問題の出る環境においてブラウザの広告ブロック系の拡張機能は特に入れていないようです。

Answer (score 1):

すみません、こちら解決しました。

ユーザーのアクセスでは別のドメイン上のURLにアクセスしており、そこでは自分のPC環境でも同じエラーが表示されました。
そのためreCAPTCHAで設定してあるドメイン上のフォームに転送させ、エラーが表示されないようにしました。